# gridview cell formatting

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview event OnRowDataBound event handler like this:

```
protected void MyGridviewEvent(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem == "Duration")
    {

    }
}
```

This selects the appropriate column in the row. I'd like to change the format of that cell. This cell contains a TimeSpan and I'd like to format it hh:mm.

How's this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
protected void MyGridviewEvent(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Duration").ToString());
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = String.Format("{0:t}", ts));
    }
}
```

Where e.Row.Cells[1] is the index of the "Duration" column.

Answer (score 3):

[GridViewRow.DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) returns the underlying datasource of this row. I doubt that it is a String like *Duration*. Normally it would be a DataRowView and you can access the datacolumn via index or name. To format a timespan you could use the .net framework 4  [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) version that takes a String with custom [format providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx). In earlier frameworks you have to do it manually.

VB.Net example(i hope you get it, the important part is the RowDataBound part)

```
 Private Sub BindGrid()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32)).AutoIncrement = True
        dt.Columns.Add("Duration", GetType(TimeSpan))
        dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns("ID")}
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        newRow("ID") = 1
        newRow("Duration") = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
        newRow = dt.NewRow
        newRow("ID") = 2
        newRow("Duration") = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(777)
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow)

        Me.GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GridRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim duration As TimeSpan = DirectCast(row("Duration"), TimeSpan)
            e.Row.Cells(1).Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", duration.TotalHours, duration.Minutes)
        End If
    End Sub
```